# How does a MasterNode fit into a Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm getting a little confused with how to setup my Spark configuration for workloads using YARN as the resource manager. I've got a small cluster spun up right now with 1 master node and 2 core nodes.

Do I include the master node when calculating the number of executors or no?

Do I leave out 1 core for every node to account for Yarn management?

Am I supposed to designate the master node for anything in particular in Spark configurations?

Comment: The Spark Driver can be ran anywhere. The master node only applies to YARN and Hadoop, not Spark without a standalone scheduler

Comment: Right, so maybe a better question to ask is: does it make sense to run the Spark Driver on the master node?

Comment: You don't control where that runs. Spark does it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Master node shouldn't be taken into account to calculate number of executors
2. Each node is actually EC2 instance with operating system so you have to leave 1 or more cores for system tasks and yarn agents
3. Master node can be used to run spark driver. For this start EMR cluster in client mode from master node by adding arguments `--master yarn --deploy-mode client` to `spark-submit` command. Keep in mind following:

   > Cluster mode allows you to submit work using S3 URIs. Client mode requires that you put the application in the local file system on the cluster master node

To do all preparation work (copy libs, scripts etc to a master node) you can setup a separate step and then run `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client` command as next step.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I mostly thought. I'm still a little confused, do I need to not allocate 1 executor for ApplicationManager? And can you help me think through calculating the # of executors for a 1 master node and 3 worker nodes setup? Each worker node has 4 cores and 8 GB of memory. I was thinking of just doing 3 cores per executor for now, so using that, `--executor-cores = 3`, `--num-executors = 2 `, and `--executor-memory 7g`

Comment: Yes you have to keep space for application master, it's not a part of executors. You can configure resources for AM similar to executors (see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties)). You can take a look at [default EMR config per instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html). Check also [this post](http://c2fo.io/c2fo/spark/aws/emr/2016/09/01/apache-spark-config-cheatsheet-part2/), there is xls file attached that can help to calculate spark config values.

Comment: BTW, I would recommend to try run EMR cluster with `maximizeResourceAllocation` set to true first before setting config manually. Check [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html) for more information.